# Understanding & designing Schema in prep for WSDL-first WS

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I'm creating a WSDL-first WS, and before I can create the WSDL, I'm hand-crafting the Schema. The is the first time I'm creating an XSD and WSDL from scratch, so please excuse my ignorance/bad practices. The client will be .NET, and server Java.

I am first creating two webservices: One to list all classes, and one to retrieve a class, and all students in that class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="classList">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="class" type="Class" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="class">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="class" type="Class"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Class">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:element name="students" type="StudentList" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="StudentList">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="student" type="Student" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Student">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Does the above schema make sense? If I generate some sample, I get the following for element classList:

```
<classList>
    <class>
        <name>String</name>
        <id>0</id>
    </class>
    <class>
        <name>String</name>
        <id>0</id>
    </class>
</classList>
```

I can choose to add students to classList, if I want. But this probably won't be done. And this for element class:

```
<class>
    <class>
        <name>String</name>
        <id>0</id>
        <students>
            <student>
                <name>String</name>
                <address>String</address>
            </student>
            <student>
                <name>String</name>
                <address>String</address>
            </student>
        </students>
    </class>
</class>
```

I'm not all that happy with the class/class naming. Since I'm designing for WSDL, should the element be something like classListResponse and classResponse?

Is it good practice that I create my entities as complexTypes, not as elements? And then create a container element to hold those entities?

Answer (score 0):

Some aspects of your question touch on stylistic issues, which by definition is main ingredient of steaming discussions... One way is to form a personal opinion, by looking up other messaging standards that may (or may not) relate to your domain of modeling. In my world, people use Rq/Rs, or Request/Response as suffixes to elements that'll show as root, or under the SOAP:Body element. There are other standards that for request have no suffix (e.g. *Operation*), and use "Response" suffix only (OperationResponse) for response elements.

As for the authoring style for XSDs, please look at articles such as [this one](http://developers.sun.com/jsenterprise/archive/nb_enterprise_pack/reference/techart/design_patterns.html). For WSDL style, [WS-I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile) is **the** reference book.

If your schema body is not that large, and makes no use of advanced features, then I would stick with a Venetian Blind-style, where all types are global and only the elements that need to be referenced from the WSDL message parts are global (input/output and faults). Use element references in your WSDL, document/literal. This should guarantee you smooth sailing.

If you build "data" services, one more thing I would consider, is to come up with a set of nouns (your entities) that describe your domain, and with a set of "verb" for intended actions (some start with basic CRUD, then add anything else specific to your domain, e.g. Cancel could be one...); Then your top level element tag names are assembled consistently using Noun + Verb + Suffix (Rq/Rs).

Regardless, always invest in setting up a simple-as-needed naming convention, it'll help in your modelling a lot!...

Comment: It's been a long week, and that is all flying way over my head. I'll have to read through that on Monday. Thank you for the response. To everyone else: Please, no flame wars.